# Haskell: catMaybe for Data.Set?

Tags: haskell, set, option-type

how would you implement a catMaybes for Data.Set ?

I came up with:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import qualified Data.Maybe as Maybe
setCatMaybes a = Set.map Maybe.fromJust . Set.delete Nothing $ a

fnord = Set.fromList [Nothing, Just 41, Just 43, Just 47]
```

then i get the following

```
setCatMaybes fnord == fromList [41,43,47]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution you already have is probably the best one.  Along the lines of John's solution, here's a fairly short one:

```
setCatMaybes :: Ord a => Set.Set (Maybe a) -> Set.Set a
setCatMaybes s = Set.fromAscList [x | Just x <- Set.toAscList s]
```

Or here's a longer one, that may be faster:

```
setCatMaybes2 :: Ord a => Set.Set (Maybe a) -> Set.Set a
setCatMaybes2 s
  | Set.null s = Set.empty
  | otherwise  = Set.mapMonotonic Maybe.fromJust $ case Set.deleteFindMin s of
                   (Nothing, s') ->  s'
                   _ -> s
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `Set (Maybe a)` is such a weird type, which appears only after the application of `f :: a -> Maybe b`, why not kill two birds with one stone and create a `mapMaybe` for `Data.Set`?

```
import qualified Data.Set
import qualified Data.Maybe

mapMaybe :: Ord b => (a -> Maybe b) -> Data.Set.Set a -> Data.Set.Set b
mapMaybe f = Data.Set.fromList . Data.Maybe.mapMaybe f . Data.Set.toList
```

In this way, the weird `Set (Maybe a)` never exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
λ> foldr (\a b -> maybe b (`Set.insert` b) a) Set.empty fnord
fromList [41,43,47]
```

Also works for other things so one could do a helper:

```
catMaybesF :: Foldable f => (a -> f a -> f a) -> f a -> f (Maybe a) -> f a
catMaybesF insert emptyf = foldr (\a b -> maybe b (`insert` b) a) emptyf

catMaybesSet = catMaybesF Set.insert Set.empty
catMaybesSeq = catMaybesF (Seq.:<|) Seq.empty
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just this:

```
setCatMaybes = Set.fromList . catMaybes
```

This will only require traversing the list once, as `Set.fromList` is a good consumer.

Comment: But the type of this list is `setCatMaybes :: (Ord a) => [Maybe a] -> Set.Set a`. Whereas i am looking for a function of the type `setCatMaybes :: (Ord a) => Set.Set (Maybe a) -> Set.Set a`

Comment: In that case your version seems the simplest, but I do think that having a `Set` of `Maybe`s is odd.  Why not just use a `Set a` with `insertMaybe mx set = (maybe id Set.insert mx) set`?

Comment: Having a set of `Maybe a` is indeed very strange! The only real difference from set of `a` is that it can also possibly contain a `Nothing`.

Comment: I have a Set `foo` of type `Set.Set a` and a function `fun :: a -> Maybe b`. I map this function over the Set with `Set.map fun foo`. That's how i get a Set of Maybes. By the way, should i choose one answer as best or is it ok to leave this topic open? I am new to Stack Overflow.